# Facebook Graph API Feed Permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question, is it possible to get the user feeds with friends permission?. That means for example, if I post something(checkin) and I choose who is going to see this post and I choose friends. 
Is it possible to get this feed? 
Beacause now I only get the public feeds.

This is the query I used for that.

```
me/feed?fields=from,full_picture,picture,id,type,link,place,privacy,is_hidden,is_instagram_eligible,feed_targeting&format=json&limit=100&with=location
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can. But you need an access_token code that has users_post permission

**About users_post permission**

> Provides access to the posts on a person's Timeline. Includes their own posts, posts they are tagged in, and posts other people make on their Timeline.

And You can see it on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_posts